# How to Make Bold the Footnotemarks Appearing After the Footnote Line

Tags: footnotes, bold

Consider the MWE

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\Large
\noindent A sentence.\footnote{Footnote A.} \\
Another sentence.\footnote{Footnote B.} \\
Another sentence.\footnote{Footnote C.}
\end{document}
```

which gives the footnotes:

[image]

I would like to make **bold** the footnotemarks (1, 2, 3 in this case) that appear after the footnote line. In the text, however, I would like to keep them as is. How may I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The footnote text is inserted via `\@makefntext` within the default document classes, so you can patch that (using [`etoolbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox)) and change its default font resetting to `\bfseries`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makefntext}% <cmd>
  {\@makefnmark}% <search>
  {\let\normalfont\bfseries\@makefnmark}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\noindent A sentence.\footnote{Footnote A.}
Another sentence.\footnote{Footnote B.}
Another sentence.\footnote{Footnote C.}

\end{document}
```

Here is the original definition of `\@makefntext` (from [`book.cls`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls?view=co)):

```
\newcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
    \parindent 1em%
    \noindent
    \hb@xt@1.8em{\hss\@makefnmark}#1}
```

The above patch changes it into

```
\newcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
    \parindent 1em%
    \noindent
    \hb@xt@1.8em{\hss\let\normalfont\bfseries\@makefnmark}#1}
```

since the definition of `\@makefnmark` (from [`latex.ltx`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latex.ltx?view=co)) is:

```
\def\@makefnmark{\hbox{\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}}
```

and issues `\normalfont`. The patch changes `\normalfont` into `\bfseries`.

Comment: Thank you kindly for both this answer and the explanations.