# Are the Packages etoolbox and scrextend Incompatible? (Trying to Increase Horizontal Space Between Bold Footnotemarks and Their Text)

Tags: spacing, footnotes, incompatibility, etoolbox, horizontal

This question is an extension of  [How to Make Bold the Footnotemarks Appearing After the Footnote Line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/618772/how-to-make-bold-the-footnotemarks-appearing-after-the-footnote-line)

Starting with the code from Werner's excellent answer which makes bold the footnotemarks after the footnote line, I am adding

```
\usepackage{scrextend}
\deffootnote[.35in]{.5in}{.195in}{\makebox[.5in][r]{\thefootnotemark.\hspace{.1in}}}
```

to augment the space between the bold footnotemarks and their associated text.

However, when I run the code

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makefntext}% <cmd>
  {\@makefnmark}% <search>
  {\let\normalfont\bfseries\@makefnmark}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother

\usepackage{scrextend}
\deffootnote[.35in]{.5in}{.195in}{\makebox[.5in][r]{\thefootnotemark.\hspace{.1in}}}
\begin{document}
\noindent A sentence.\footnote{Footnote A.}
Another sentence.\footnote{Footnote B.}
Another sentence.\footnote{Footnote C.}
\end{document}
```

I get the spacing adjustment I am looking for---but the footnotemarks are no longer bold.

[image]

Remark: I have discovered that when I run Werner's code with only the package `scrextend` added, the footnotemarks are no longer bold:

[image]

QUESTION: Are the packages `etoolbox` and `scrextend` incompatible? (and) How may I increase the horizontal spacing between each footnotemark and its text for each such mark below the footnote line?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\deffootnote` redefines the footnote code and so overwrites also your patch. But you can add the bold font simply to the definition there:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{scrextend}
\deffootnote[.35in]{.5in}{.195in}{\makebox[.5in][r]{\bfseries\thefootnotemark.\hspace{.1in}}}

\begin{document}
\noindent A sentence.\footnote{Footnote A.}
Another sentence.\footnote{Footnote B.}
Another sentence.\footnote{Footnote C.}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

With package `scrextend` and `\deffootnote` you can use `\addtokomafont` or `\setkomafont` to change the font settings for the footnotemark:

```latex
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{scrextend}
\setkomafont{footnotelabel}{\bfseries}
\deffootnote[.35in]{.5in}{.195in}{\makebox[.5in][r]{\thefootnotemark.\hspace{.1in}}}

\begin{document}
\noindent A sentence.\footnote{Footnote A.}
Another sentence.\footnote{Footnote B.}
Another sentence.\footnote{Footnote C.}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Using `\addtokomafont` or `\setkomafont` you can also change the font settings of the footnotemarks and the footnote text:

```latex
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{scrextend}
\setkomafont{footnote}{\itshape}
\setkomafont{footnotelabel}{\bfseries}
\deffootnote[.35in]{.5in}{.195in}{\makebox[.5in][r]{\thefootnotemark.\hspace{.1in}}}

\begin{document}
\noindent A sentence.\footnote{Footnote A.}
Another sentence.\footnote{Footnote B.}
Another sentence.\footnote{Footnote C.}
\end{document}
```

[image]